# Div not floating correctly after moving to responsive and back

Tags: html, css

I have a footer on a webpage. Some copyright text floats to the left of the page, and there are some footer items to the right. The copyright div should stack below the rest of the footer details when it moves to the responsive. All of this works fine except for when you move below 640 and then back to a larger view again. The floated div sits below the other footer items.

This is an issue on chrome but not IE.

See the [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/simoncowie/pen/fByIw) here.

Html:

```
<div id="footerSectionWrapper">
    <div id="footerSection">
        <ul id="footerList">
            <li class="details">
         <p> details text </p>
            </li>
       <li class="contact">
          <p> contact number: 123</p>
       </li>
            <li class="resources">
         <p> Some links! </p>
            </li>
            <li class="services">
         <p> Other stuff!</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="copyrightSection">
      <p> Copyright text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
  </div><!--/footerSection-->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!--/footerSectionWrapper-->
```

Css:

```
#footerSectionWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

#footerSection {
    background-color:red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#footerList {
    background-color: blue;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center !important;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}

#footerList li {
    background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid darkblue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: auto;
}

#copyrightSection {
    background-color:yellow;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

@media all and (min-width:641px){
  #footerList {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
  }

  #footerList li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    text-align: left;
    }

  #footerList li.details, li.contact {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding-top: 50px !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  #footerList li.services, li.resources {
    padding-bottom: 250px !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
  }

  #copyrightSection {
    width: 39%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did it work for you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set float:left also to the generic css on top and not only inside the media query.

```
#copyrightSection {
    background-color:yellow;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
}
```

Check this pen. http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/ctAud

Add **float:left;** also to the first set of css rules for #copyrightSection outside the media queries.